# Definite integral calculation with poles at $0$ and $\pm i\sqrt{3}$

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(2\pi x)}{x(x^2+3)} \, dx$$

I looked at $\frac{e^{2\pi i z}}{z^{3}+3z}$, also calculated the residues, but they don't get me the right answer. I used that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(z)\,dz = 2\pi i (\sum \operatorname{Res} z_r) + \pi i \operatorname{Res}_0$, but my answer turns out wrong when I check with wolframalpha.

Residue for $0$ is $1$, for $z=\sqrt{3}i$ it's $-\frac{e^{-2\pi}}{2}$ . . .

In a worse attempt I forgot $2\pi$ and used $z$ only (i.e. $\frac{e^{iz}}{z^{3}+3z}$) and the result was a little closer, but missing a factor of 2 and and $i$.

**Can anyone see the right way? Please do tell.**

Comment: How do you get the residue at 0 to be 1?

Comment: Once you calculated the residue of $f(z) = \frac{e^{2\pi i z}}{z(z^2+3)}$ at $z = 0$ and $z = i\sqrt{3}$, you will get $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} = 2\pi i \operatorname{Res}_{z=i\sqrt{3}} f(z) + \pi i \operatorname{Res}_{z=0} f(z).$$ Then the actual answer must be $\frac{1}{2i} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(z) \; dz$. I guess this is what you have missed.

Comment: Hey sos440, I do get the right answer with $\frac{1}{2i}$, the $\frac{1}{2}$ comes from the integration boundaries, and the $\frac{1}{i}$ because sine is the imaginary part of $e^{iz}$, right?

Comment: @VVV , what contour are you taking for your calculations?? Also, after the limit when $\,R\to\infty\,$ (or whatever) is done, we still remain with the real part of the complex function ($\,cos 2\pi x\,$ instead of $\,\sin 2\pi x\,$, which does *not* converge on $\,(0,\infty)\,$... Also, you seem to be taking a contour that contains only the positive imaginary pole and not the negative one.

Comment: @sos440 , what contour are you taking for your calculations? and why the integral is multiplied by $\,1/2i\,$ and not by $\,1/2\pi i\,$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio, The contour I used is a semicircular contour with small indent at the origin, see [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/File:ContourSinzz.gif). Also, we are not calculating the residue of $f(z)$, which means that there is no need to divide the integral by $2\pi i$. The factor $\frac{1}{2i}$ arises because our goal is to evaluate $$\Im \int_{0}^{\infty} f(z) \; dz = \frac{1}{2i}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(z)\;dz.$$

Comment: @sos440 , thanks for the comment. Would you mind writing down an answer for this (and thus rescue this poor question from the unanwered questions' dragon)? I understand that Jordan's lemma gives us that the integral on the indentend part tends to zero when epsilon does, and on the large arc also the same whe $\,R\to\infty\,$, yet I still cannot get the correct result which according to WA is $$\frac{\pi}{6}\left(1-e^{-2\sqrt 3 \pi}\right)$$. I can't get that one inside the parentheses.

Comment: The discontinuity at $x=0$ in $x\mapsto \dfrac{\sin(2\pi x)} x$ is removable, so your statement about a residue at $0$ is mistaken. $\qquad$

Answer (score 31):

We make the following lemma:

> **Lemma.** Suppose $f(z)$ is holomorphic near $z = z_0$. Fix $\theta_0 \in (0, 2\pi)$. If $\gamma_\varepsilon$ denotes a counter-clockwise oriented arc of angle $\theta_0$ on the circle of radius $\varepsilon$ centered at $z_0$, then
> $$ \lim_{\varepsilon\to0} \int_{\gamma_\varepsilon} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z_0}\;d\zeta=i\theta_0 f(z_0).$$

> *Proof.* By the substitution $\zeta = z_0 + \varepsilon e^{i\theta}$, we have
> $$\begin{align*}
> \left| \int_{\gamma_\varepsilon} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z_0}\;d\zeta - i\theta_0 f(z_0)\right|
> &= \left| i \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_1+\theta_0} f(z_0 + \varepsilon e^{i\theta})\;d\theta - i\theta_0 f(z_0)\right| \\
> & \leq \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_1+\theta_0} \left| f(z_0 + \varepsilon e^{i\theta}) - f(z_0) \right| \;d\theta,
> \end{align*}$$
> which clearly goes to zero when $\varepsilon \to 0$.

As a corollary, if $f(z)$ has a simple pole at $z = z_0$ then with the same notation as in the Lemma, we have

$$ \lim_{\varepsilon\to0} \int_{\gamma_\varepsilon} f(\zeta) \;d\zeta=i\theta_0 \operatorname{Res} \{ f(z), z_0 \}.$$

Now let $C$ be the upper-semicircular contour of radius $R \gg 1$ with a small semicircular indent of radius $\varepsilon \ll 1$ at the origin. Let us write $C$ as
$$ C = \Gamma_{R} + L_{\varepsilon,R} - \gamma_\varepsilon,$$
where $\Gamma_R$ and $\gamma_\varepsilon$ denote counter-clockwise oriented arcs corresponding to the outer circle and the inner circle of $C$, respectively, and $L_{\varepsilon,R}$ denote the remaining union of two lines on $C \cap \Bbb{R}$. Now for

$$ f(z) = \frac{e^{2\pi i z}}{z(z^2 + 3)}, $$

the integral in question, which we denote as $I$, is equal to

$$I = \frac{1}{2i} \lim_{{\varepsilon \to 0 \atop R \to \infty}} \int_{L_{\varepsilon, R}} f(z) \; dz.$$

Now, by Cauchy integration formula,

$$ \oint_{C} f(z) \; dz = 2\pi i \operatorname{Res} \{ f(z), i\sqrt{3} \}. $$

This means that

$$ \int_{L_{\varepsilon, R}} f(z) \; dz = 2\pi i \operatorname{Res} \{ f(z), i\sqrt{3} \} + \int_{\gamma_\varepsilon} f(z) \; dz - \int_{\Gamma_R} f(z) \; dz. $$

Taking limit $\varepsilon \to 0$ and $R \to \infty$, the integral $\int_{\Gamma_R} f(z) \; dz$ vanishes by Jordan's lemma. Thus by our lemma,

$$ \lim_{{var\epsilon \to 0 \atop R \to \infty}} \int_{L_{\varepsilon, R}} f(z) \; dz = 2\pi i \operatorname{Res} \{ f(z), i\sqrt{3} \} + \pi i \operatorname{Res} \{ f(z), 0 \}.$$

But since

$$ \operatorname{Res} \{ f(z), i\sqrt{3} \} = \left. (z-i\sqrt{3})f(z) \right|_{z=i\sqrt{3}} = -\frac{1}{6}e^{-2\pi \sqrt{3}} $$

and

$$ \operatorname{Res} \{ f(z), 0 \} = \left. z f(z) \right|_{z=0} = \frac{1}{3}, $$

we have

$$ I = \frac{1}{2i} \left[ 2\pi i \left(-\frac{1}{6}e^{-2\pi \sqrt{3}}\right) + \pi i \left(\frac{1}{3} \right) \right] = \frac{\pi}{6}\left(1 - e^{-2\pi \sqrt{3}} \right). $$

Comment: +1 Very nice answer! Not only was I answered but I also learned about a rather beautiful, and hopefully pretty useful, generalization of Cauchy's Integral Theorem. Thanks a lot, @sos440

Comment: Could someone help me with the proof of the corollary?

Answer (score 8):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(2\pi x)}{x(x^2+3)}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(2\pi x)}{x(x^2+3)}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=\frac12\int_{i-\infty}^{i+\infty}\frac{\sin(2\pi z)}{z(z^2+3)}\,\mathrm{d}z\tag{2}\\
&=\frac12\int_{i-\infty}^{i+\infty}\frac{e^{i2\pi z}-e^{-i2\pi z}}{2iz(z^2+3)}\,\mathrm{d}z\tag{3}\\
&=\frac1{4i}\int_{\gamma_+}\frac{e^{i2\pi z}}{z(z^2+3)}\mathrm{d}z
-\frac1{4i}\int_{\gamma_-}\frac{e^{-i2\pi z}}{z(z^2+3)}\mathrm{d}z\tag{4}\\
&=\frac{2\pi i}{4i}\frac{e^{-2\pi\sqrt3}}{i\sqrt3(i\sqrt3+i\sqrt3)}
+\frac{2\pi i}{4i}\left(\frac13+\frac{e^{-2\pi\sqrt3}}{-i\sqrt3(-i\sqrt3-i\sqrt3)}\right)\tag{5}\\
&=\frac\pi6\left(1-e^{-2\pi\sqrt3}\right)\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
where $\gamma_+$ passes from $i-R$ to $i+R$ then circles back counterclockwise around the upper half-plane, and where $\gamma_-$ passes from $i-R$ to $i+R$ then circles back clockwise around the lower half-plane.

$\gamma_+$ contains the singularity at $i\sqrt3$.

$\gamma_-$ contains the singularities at $0$ and  $-i\sqrt3$.

**Explanation of steps**

$(1)$ integrand is an even function.

$(2)$ there are no singularities for the integrand in the rectangle with corners $i-R,i+R,R,-R$ and the integral over the ends of the rectangle vanishes as $R\to\infty$.

$(3)$ write $\sin(2\pi z)=\dfrac{e^{i2\pi z}-e^{-i2\pi z}}{2i}$

$(4)$ use contour $\gamma_+$ for $e^{i2\pi z}$ and $\gamma_-$ for $e^{-i2\pi z}$ so that the integrand vanishes over the large circles in the upper and lower half-planes.

$(5)$ use residues to compute the integrals over $\gamma_+$ and $\gamma_-$.

$(6)$ simplification.

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#00f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{2\pi x} \over x\pars{x^{2} + 3}}\,\dd x}=
\half\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{2\pi x} \over x\pars{x^{2} + 3}}\,\dd x
=\pi\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{1 \over x^{2} + 3}\,\pars{\half\int_{-1}^{1}\expo{2\pi\ic k x}\,\dd k}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&={\pi \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}\dd k
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{2\pi\ic kx} \over x^{2} + 3}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&={\pi \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}\bracks{%
\Theta\pars{-k}\pars{-2\pi\ic}\,
{\expo{2\pi\ic k\pars{-\ic\root{3}}} \over -2\ic\root{3}}
+\Theta\pars{k}\pars{2\pi\ic}\,
{\expo{2\pi\ic k\pars{\ic\root{3}}} \over 2\ic\root{3}}}\,\dd k
\\[3mm]&={\pi \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}{\pi \over \root{3}}\,
\expo{-2\pi\root{3}\verts{k}}\,\dd k
={\root{3} \over 3}\,\pi^{2}\int_{0}^{1}\expo{-2\pi\root{3}k}\,\dd k
\\[3mm]&={\root{3} \over 3}\,\pi^{2}\,{\expo{-2\pi\root{3}} - 1 \over -2\pi\root{3}}
=\color{#00f}{\large{1 \over 6}\,\pi\pars{1 - \expo{-2\pi\root{3}}}}
\end{align}

Comment: What is $\Theta$ in this context?

Comment: @user170231 Heaviside Step Function.

Answer (score 1):

Given that to solve  Integral

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2\pi x) }{x(x^2+3)}dx$$

Assume that $$\mathcal{I}(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x(x²+1)}dx \to (1)$$ here $a$ is positive real

Differentiating $(1) $ we get

$$\mathcal{I}'=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax) }{x^2+3}dx$$

Now it is easy to use complex analysis by taking function $$f(z) =\frac{e^{\iota az}}{z^2+3}$$
and using Jordan inequality we will get
$$\mathcal{I}'(a) =\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}e^{-\sqrt{3}a}$$

Now integrate the expression

$$\mathcal{I}(a) =-\frac{\pi}{6}e^{-a\sqrt{3}}+C$$

Where $C $ is constant of integration
Since $\mathcal{I}(0) =0$ then
$C=\frac{\pi}{6}$
Combine every thing put the value of a and we are done

Answer (score 0):

Resolving $\frac{1}{x(x^2+1)}$  into partial fractions yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (2 \pi x)}{x\left(x^{2}+3\right)} d x &=\frac{1}{3}\left( \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (2 \pi x)}{x} dx-\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2} \sin (2 \pi x)}{x^{2}+3} dx \right)\\
&=\frac{1}{6}\left(\pi-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x \sin (2 \pi x)}{x^{2}+3} d x\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

By Jordan’s Lemma,
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x \cos (2 \pi x)}{x^{2}+3} d x+i \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x \sin (2 \pi x)}{x^{2}+3} d x \\
=& 2 \pi i \operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{z e^{2 \pi zi}}{z^{2}+3}, z=\sqrt 3 i\right)\\
=& 2 \pi i \frac{\sqrt{3} i e^{-2 \sqrt{3} \pi}}{2 \sqrt{3} i} \\
=& \pi ie^{-2 \sqrt{3} \pi},
\end{aligned}
$$

using contour integration along anti-clockwise direction of the path $$\gamma=\gamma_{1} \cup \gamma_{2} \textrm{ where }  \gamma_{1}(t)=t+i 0(-R \leq t \leq R)  \textrm{ and } \gamma_{2}(t)=R e^{i t}  (0<t<\pi) $$

Comparing the imaginary parts of both sides gives
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x \sin (2 \pi x)}{x^{2}+3} d x = \pi e^{-2 \sqrt{3} \pi} $$

Hence $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (2 \pi x)}{x\left(x^{2}+3\right)} d x = \frac{\pi}{6}\left(1-e^{-2 \sqrt{3} \pi}\right) $$