# Improper integral of sin(x)/x from zero to infinity

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I was having trouble with the following integral:
$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx$. My question is, how does one go about evaluating this, since its existence seems fairly intuitive, while its solution, at least to me, does not seem particularly obvious.

Comment: The title is unrelated to the question in the main body.

Comment: [Here's a couple.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192685/are-there-any-ways-to-evaluate-int-infty-0-frac-sin-xxdx-without-using-d)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Let $I(s)$ be given by

$$I(s)=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-sx}\sin(x)}{x}\,dx \tag1$$

for $s\ge 0$.  Note that $\lim_{s\to \infty}I(s)=0$ and that $I(0)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx$ is the integral of interest.

---

Differentiating $I(s)$ as given by $(1)$ (this is justified by uniform convergence of the "differentiated" integral for $s\ge \delta>0$) reveals

$$\begin{align}
I'(s)&=-\int_0^\infty e^{-sx}\sin(x)\,dx\\\\
&=-\frac{1}{1+s^2} \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Integrating $(2)$, we find that $I(s)=\pi/2-\arctan(s)$ whence setting $s=0$ yields the coveted result

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx=\frac\pi2$$

Comment: How do you compute the integral of $e^{-sx}\sin(x)$?

Comment: @user39082 There are a variety of ways.  One way forward, we write $\sin(x)=\text{Im}(e^{ix})$.

Comment: integrating $-\dfrac{1}{1+s^2}$ just equals $-\arctan(s)$. How should this equal $\pi/2-\arctan(s)$ ?

Comment: @leon Clearly we have $$I(s)=\int_s^\infty  \frac1{s'^2+1}\,ds'=\frac\pi2 -\arctan(s)$$

Comment: But don't we got $\displaystyle{\int_s^{\infty} -\dfrac{1}{{s'}^2+1}\,\mathrm{ds'} = -\frac{\pi}{2}+\arctan{s}}$ ?

Comment: @leon Leon, it's evident that we have $$\int_s^\infty -\frac1{s'^2+1}\,ds'=-I(s)$$

Comment: @MarkViola could you explain why it becomes $I(s)=\int_s^\infty \frac{1}{s'^2+1}ds^\prime$ instead of $\int_0^s \frac{1}{s' ^2+1}ds^\prime$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MessiLio $I(0)\ne 0$, which is the implication of the statement $I(s)=\int_0^s \frac1{s'^2+1}\,ds'$.  $I(s)=\lim_{s\to\infty}\int_s^\infty \frac1{s'^2+1}\,ds'$ implies that $I(s)\to 0$ as $s\to \infty$ is consistent.   Does that make sense?

Comment: I think this argumentation is not completely finished: As you write, $I'(s)$ can be only computed for $s > 0$, but after integrating you plug in $s = 0$, however the equality $I(s) = \pi / 2 - \arctan(s)$ has only been shown for $s > 0$. You need some additional machinery to make this rigorous, i.e. show that the integral $$\int_0^b e^{-sx} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$ converges uniformly in $s> 0$ to $$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-sx} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$ for $b \to \infty$. This requires a bit of work. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Richard Actually, the improper integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-sx}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx$ converges uniformly for $s\ge 0$.  Hence, $I(s)$ is continuous for $s\in [0,\infty)$ and we have $\lim_{s\to 0^+}I(s)=I(0)$.  So, there is no issue with the analysis herein.

Comment: @MarkViola ok, I have somehow overread that you wrote this in your answer, sorry ...

Comment: @user39082 Integration by parts should do nicely.