# Rigorously justifying the Leibniz rule for integration for improper integrals

Tags: calculus

I am interested in proving rigorously the use of the Leibniz rule for integration on the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx$$
In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2322547/improper-integral-of-sinx-x-from-zero-to-infinity) the integral is written as

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)e^{-\alpha x}}{x}dx$$
and it is then differentiated with respect to alpha. The author of the answer mentions that "this is justified by uniform convergence of the "differentiated" integral for ≥>0". However, I am not really sure what this means.

Could you please provide a step by step proof of why we are allowed to use the Leibniz rule in this particular example?
I would really appreciate any help.

Edit: I read that it is necessary to prove uniform convergence of the integral. But how would one go about doing that?

Comment: it’s not an *indefinite* integral, it is an *improper* integral. Next, it is not *necessary* to prove uniform convergence; it (and perhaps some other stuff) is a *sufficient* condition. Leibniz’s integral rule has varying levels of generality. If you know about Lebesgue integrals, and dominated convergence then this is pretty obvious. Otherwise, it requires some more finesse.

Comment: @peek-a-boo the improper Riemann integral $\int_0^\infty (\sin x)/x\,dx$ converges but $(\sin x)/x$ on $[0,\infty)$ is not Lebesgue integrable (since $\int_0^\infty |(\sin x)/x|\,dx = \infty$), so I am suspicious about using Lebesgue integrals and the dominated convergence theorem alone to justify the evaluation of $\int_0^\infty (\sin x)/x\,dx$ by passage to the limit of $\int_0^\infty (\sin x)e^{-\alpha x}/x\,dx$ as $\alpha \to 0^+$ without any finesse.

Comment: @KCd yes that’s certainly true; I was merely addressing the issue of justifying the differentiation under the integral sign.

Comment: Ah, okay. The next step, justifying that setting $\alpha = 0$ in the formula for $\int_0^\infty (\sin x)e^{-\alpha x}/x\,dx$ from Leibniz when $\alpha > 0$ gives you the correct value of the integral at $\alpha = 0$ needs some more finesse as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

See https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/diffunderint.pdf: Section $3$, the second row of Table $2$ on page $16$ (this is related to the uniform convergence asked about), and the appendix.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1901551)

Comment: @C-RAM  I have edited the answer to include the link explicitly; its details are too long for me to put here.  I think it is a bit absurd for someone to be voting to *delete* this answer (2 so far) when it shows the OP precisely where to look to get an answer.

Comment: +1 I don't know what's happened to math.se over the last few years, but the site isn't what it used to be.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, your answer is indeed a good resource for the asker, but as someone who has been silently using MSE for the past 6-7 years, the amount of old answer links that just don't work does get on my nerves, and that's precisely the problem with such link-only answers; sometimes they break over time. However, this seems to me like it would make an excellent comment, which perhaps someone may use to construct a full answer here. I don't claim to fully understand the reasoning behind the higher level users who voted to delete, but that was my logic.

Comment: @C-RAM  I don't have the time right now to write up a more detailed answer.  I'll try to return to this later.