# Using $e^{ix}$ instead of sine and cosine in contour integration

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, analysis

A while ago I asked:

[Evaluation of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(x)/(x^2+1)$ using complex analysis.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1077581/evaluation-of-int-0-infty-cosx-x21-using-complex-analysis/1077636)

Instead of using $\cos(z)$ an answerer said that is valid to use $e^{ix}$

How is this valid? I dont understand that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\cos z = \Re(e^{iz})$ and $\Re$ is a linear operator, so $\Re\int = \int\Re$.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Jack. But this is contour integration. Does the rule you state in the end still apply complex-contour integration?

Comment: @Amad27: yes, $\Re$ commutes with $\oint$, too.

Comment: So we we are doing is this:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(z)}{z^2 + 1} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\text{Re}e^{iz}}{z^2 + 1} = \text{Re}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2 + 1}$

So if the answer is for example, $2i$ we take Re[$2i$] = 0?

just as an example, not that that is the actual value of the integral?

Comment: @Amad27: exactly.

Comment: @Amad27: you're welcome.