# Bounding complex contour integrals

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, limits

**Background:** We wish to compute $$\int_0^\pi \left| i\epsilon e^{i\theta}\cdot\frac{e^{i\alpha}e^{i\alpha \epsilon e^{i\theta}}}{(1+\epsilon e^{i\theta})^4-1}\right|\,d\theta$$This arises from taking a small contour of radius $\epsilon$ around the point $z=1$ where you had some complex function with $z^4-1$ in the denominator. We have $\alpha\in\Bbb R$.

**Question:** How can I find the value of this as $\epsilon\to0$?

**Attempt:** $$=\int_0^\pi\frac{e^{-\alpha \epsilon \sin\theta}}{|\epsilon^3e^{3i\theta}+4\epsilon^2 e^{2i\theta}+6\epsilon e^{i\theta}+4|}\,d\theta$$I am not sure what to do with the denominator now. It seems as $\epsilon\to0$, we just get $\pi/4$. Is it this simple? I was expecting the whole thing to go to $0$, but it seems that is not the case?

Comment: Note: If you are trying to show that the contribution from a small contour like this is negligible and you get $\pi/4$, this is not really useful to you and you'd have to work out the exact value. (I suspect you had used something like $\left|\int\cdot\,d\theta\right|\le\int\left|\cdot\right|\,d\theta$ in a previous step in arriving here.)

Comment: Yes thas right, which is why i was hoping it goes to $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral is equal to $\frac{\pi}4$.
Taking the limit into the integral is allowed.

Just as what @JohnDoe commented, the estimation is not so useful.

Note that
$$\text{Res}_{z=1}\frac{e^{iaz}}{z^4-1}=2I$$ where $I$ is your integral(without absolute values).

I am 90% confident it is not a coincidence that
$$|2\pi\text{Res}_{z=k}f(z)|=|\oint f(z)dz|=\int^{2\pi}_0 |f(k+\epsilon e^{i\theta})|d\theta$$

Here, $f(z)= \frac{e^{iaz}}{z^4-1}$,
You evaluated integral equals(with absolute values) $\pi/4$ while 
$$\text{Res}_{z=1}f(z)=\frac{e^{ia}}4$$

**EDIT:**

Answer to the question in your comment: Yes.

A useful lemma from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83828/definite-integral-calculation-with-poles-at-0-and-pm-i-sqrt3) by [@SangchulLee](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9340/sangchul-lee):

> **Lemma.** Suppose $f(z)$ is holomorphic near $z = z_0$. Fix $\theta_0 \in (0, 2\pi)$. If $\gamma_{\epsilon}$ denotes a counter-clockwise oriented arc of angle $\theta_0$ on the circle of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $z_0$, then
>   $$ \lim_{\epsilon\to0} \int_{\gamma_{\epsilon}} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z_0}\;d\zeta=i\theta_0 f(z_0).$$
>
> *Proof.* By the substitution $\zeta = z_0 + \epsilon e^{i\theta}$, we have
>   $$\begin{align*}
> \left| \int_{\gamma_{\epsilon}} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z_0}\;d\zeta - i\theta_0 f(z_0)\right|
> &= \left| i \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_1+\theta_0} f(z_0 + \epsilon e^{i\theta})\;d\theta - i\theta_0 f(z_0)\right| \\
> & \leq \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_1+\theta_0} \left| f(z_0 + \epsilon e^{i\theta}) - f(z_0) \right| \;d\theta,
> \end{align*}$$
>   which clearly goes to zero when $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: Okay so the contribution to my complex contour integral can be evaluated in a similar way to how you use the residue theorem for a singularity inside the contour, but by halving it?

Comment: @dialog See my edited answer.