# $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{x^5+1}dx$ using contour integration.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, complex-integration

I am wondering if I have correctly computed this integral, which I see in a lot of posts as being really hard.

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{x^5+1}dx$. Consider the following contour:

[image]

The poles of $\frac{1}{z^5+1}$ occur at $e^{i\left(\frac{\pi}{5} + \frac{2\pi}{5} n\right)}$ where $n=0,1,2,3,4$. Our contour only includes the poles $n=0,1$.

First, we compute the outermost circle. We parameterize the integral with $\gamma_1(t) = Re^{it}-1$ where $0\leq t \leq \pi$.

$$\int_{\gamma_1}\frac{1}{z^5+1}dz = \int_0^{\pi}\frac{Rie^{it}}{(Re^{it}-1)^5+1}dt.$$

Then taking $R \to \infty$, since the $R$ term in the denominator dominates,

$$\lim_{R\to \infty} \left|\int_0^{\pi}\frac{Rie^{it}}{(Re^{it}-1)^5+1}dt \right|\leq \lim_{R\to\infty}\pi \sup_{t}\left|\frac{Rie^{it}}{(Re^{it}-1)^5+1}\right|= 0$$

and now for the inner circle $\gamma_2(t) = \epsilon e^{-i\theta}-1$ $0\leq \theta \leq \pi$, by the binomial formula,

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_0^{\pi}\frac{-\epsilon ie^{it}}{(\epsilon e^{it} -1)^5+1}dt \\
=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{0}^\pi \frac{-\epsilon i e^{it}}{\epsilon^5 e^{5 i t}-5 \epsilon^4 e^{4 i t}+10 \epsilon^3 e^{3 i t}-10 \epsilon^2 e^{2 i t}+5 \epsilon e^{i t}-1 + 1}dt\\
=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{0}^\pi \frac{-i}{\epsilon^4 e^{4 i t}-5 \epsilon^3 e^{3 i t}+10 \epsilon^2 e^{2 i t}-10 \epsilon e^{ i t}+5}dt\\
=-\frac{i\pi}{5}.$$

Now it remains to just compute the residues inside the contour. Both poles are simple, so by the residue formula,

$$\lim_{z\to e^{i\frac{\pi}{5}}} \frac{(z-e^{i\frac{\pi}{5}})}{z^5+1}= \frac{1}{5e^{i\frac{4\pi}{5}}}$$

and

$$\lim_{z\to e^{i\frac{3\pi}{5}}} \frac{(z-e^{i(\frac{3\pi}{5})})}{z^5+1}= \frac{1}{5e^{i\frac{12\pi}{5}}}$$

Then by the residue theorem,

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{x^5+1}dx  = 2\pi i \left[\frac{1}{5e^{i\frac{4\pi}{5}}} + \frac{1}{5e^{i\frac{12\pi}{5}}}\right]+\frac{i\pi}{5}= \frac{1}{5} \sqrt{5 + 2 \sqrt{5}}\pi.$$

Comment: The integral is obvious real, so you should simplify your answer to a real number. (And I assume you mean the principal value integral?)

Comment: I think you made a mistake (or typo) it should be: $$\frac{1}{5e^{4(i\frac{\pi}{5}+\frac{2\pi}{5})}}$$

Comment: @Masd isn’t that equivalent?

Comment: @random_0620 if you added brackets

Comment: $$(e^{a})^b \neq {e^{a^b}}$$

Comment: @Masd good point I will correct the notation thank you

Comment: Your *“inner circle $\gamma_2(t) = \epsilon e^{i\theta}$”* is not a half circle around $z=-1$, as shown in the picture. And why is there an $R$ in the denominator?

Comment: @MartinR ah you’re right I needed to make these centered at -1, though I believe they still vanish after the limit. I will fix this

Comment: As @HansLundmark comments, the integral is ambiguous without specifying something like "principal value" at the bad point $-1$. And, even then, taking the limit of small arcs above the bad point does not produce the principal value integral. (See Sokhotski-Plemelj theorem about this.)

Comment: @random_0620: The contribution of the inner half circle contour is *not* zero.

Comment: @MartinR I see that now. I'm not sure how to go about evaluating this integral.

Comment: @random_0620: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/319959/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4720008/42969.

Comment: @MartinR I computed that part and I got $\frac{\pi}{5}$. Do you agree now?

Comment: Why don't you simplify $\frac{\pi}{5} + \frac{2\pi}{5} = \frac{3\pi}{5}$ when identifying the second point?  It looks like not doing so resulted in an error/typo in the final line.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thank you I did this. The final answer is still complex suggesting something is off still

Comment: @MartinR Thank you fixed, still has an imaginary part unfortunately when I plug into wolfram

Comment: At first glance, it seems you're traversing the inner circle backwards, so the sign is reversed.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Ah! Thank you now its real

Comment: Your integral is a special case of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110457/42969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check your answer (when you get it)...
Maple evaluates
$$
\int_{-1+a}^{\infty }\! \left( {x}^{5}+1 \right) ^{-1}\,{\rm d}x+\int_
{-\infty }^{-1-a}\! \left( {x}^{5}+1 \right) ^{-1}\,{\rm d}x
$$
where $a>0$.  The answer is half a page long with some arctangents and square-roots in it.  The limit as $a \to 0^+$ is
$$
{\frac {\pi\,\sqrt {10-2\,\sqrt {5}} \left( \sqrt {5}+3 \right) }{20}}
\approx 1.93377
$$

Comment: Oh, I'm only mildly disappointed that you didn't show the huge-and-ugly result for arbitrary $a>0$ :)

Comment: Looks good! Thank you to @Martin R and paul garrett for their help.