# Improper integral with residue theorem and interpretation

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

I have the following integral:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2+b}{(x-1)^3(x+1)^3}dx,
$$

which I want to solve by complex integration (is it possible? That's my first question).

Now, by using the following contour:

$$
C_R=[-R,-1-\epsilon]\cup\{-1+\epsilon e^{i\theta};0\leq\theta\leq\pi\}\cup[-1+\epsilon,1-\epsilon]\cup\{1+\epsilon e^{i\theta};0\leq\theta\leq\pi\}\cup[1+\epsilon,R],
$$

so that

$$
\oint_{C_R}f(z)dz=0,
$$

and in the limits as $R\to\infty$ and $\epsilon\to0$:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2+b}{(x-1)^3(x+1)^3}=-\lim_{\epsilon\to0}(\text{integrals on the semi-circles}).
$$

For the semicircle around $x=-1$, let $z=-1+\epsilon e^{i\theta}$, so that:

$$
\text{integral semi-circle 1}=\int_\pi^0\frac{(-1+\epsilon e^{i\theta})^2+b}{(-1+\epsilon e^{i\theta}-1)^3(-1+\epsilon e^{i\theta}+1)^3}(i \epsilon e^{i\theta}d\theta)=\frac{i}{\epsilon^2}\int_\pi^0 e^{i\theta}\frac{(-1+\epsilon e^{i\theta})^2+b}{(-2+\epsilon e^{i\theta})^3(e^{i\theta})^3}d\theta,
$$

which diverges in the limit as $\epsilon\to0$, just like the other remaining integral.

The latter makes sense when one looks at the plot of $f(x)$.

But, on the other hand, the corollary in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83828/definite-integral-calculation-with-poles-at-0-and-pm-i-sqrt3/184874#184874) (if I understood it correctly) implies that:

$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\text{integral semi-circle 1}=i\pi\text{Res}(z_0=-1)=\frac{1}{16}(1-3b),
$$

and then

$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to0}(\text{integrals on the semi-circles})=0,
$$

which contradicts the first result.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: The integral diverges. Also, neither pole here is simple, as opposed to the example you cite.